# How can I add a custom color function and a custom mesh to a 3D parametric plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

Consider a pseudosphere,

$\qquad \{x,y,z\} = \{\sin[u] \cos[v],\, \sin[u] \sin[v], \, \log[\tan[u/2]\}$.

Now I want to draw the figure.

```
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Log[Tan[u/2]] + Cos[u]}, 
  {u, -2 π, 2 π}, {v, -2 π, 2 π}]
```

Now I want to have the plot show the following:

1. All points with equal third coordinate has the same color.
2. A curve with constant third coordinate is shown on the surface. it is equal to $\cos(u)\cot(u) = 0$.

I don't know how to combine these requirements. I tried

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Log[Tan[u/2]] + Cos[u]}, 
  {u, -2 π, 2 π}, {v, -2 π, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Mesh -> 10, 
  MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[#, f'[#] == 0] &}]
```

but it didn't help.

Any help I get here will be appreciated!

Comment: Something like this `MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)`?

Comment: @swish I guess that doesn't give us a $cos(x) = 0 $ property

Comment: And where $cos(x)=0$ comes from?

Comment: @swish from second property : curve with constant third coordinate is curve according to $z'(u) = 0 = cos(u)cot(u)$, i.e. $cos(u) = 0$

Comment: @swish I thought about using ConditionalExpression in MeshFunctions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives a plot of the pseudosphere with coloring according to its z-coordinates.

```
p1 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Log[Tan[u/2]] + Cos[u]},
    {u, -2 π, 2 π}, {v, -2 π, 2 π},
    PlotPoints -> 20,
    MaxRecursion -> 3,  
    ColorFunction -> ((Hue[Abs@#3]) &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    Mesh -> None,
    Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: plot1]

To find where `Cos[u] Cot[u] == 0` holds in the domain -2 π <= u <= 2 π, I evaluate

```
uVals = 
  DeleteDuplicates[u /. Solve[Cos[u] Cot[u] == 0 && -2 π <= u <= 2 π, u]]
```

which gives

> `{-((3 π)/2), -(π/2), π/2, (3 π)/2}`

The z-coordinates corresponding to these values of `u` are

```
zVals = Log[Tan[#/2]] + Cos[#] & /@ uVals
```

> `{0, I π, 0, I π}`

So the only curve satisfying your condition is at `z == 0`, which occurs at two `u` values and I arbitrarily pick `u == π/2`.

The curve can be plotted with

```
p2 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[{Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Log[Tan[u/2]] + Cos[u]} /. u -> π/2],
    {u, -2 π, 2 π}, {v, -2 π, 2 π},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[4]]];
```

`p2` is not interesting plotted on its own, so I will only show it combined with `p1`, which I now give

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

plot2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specify all the solution points for `Mesh` parameter:

```
Mesh -> {u /. Solve[z'[u] == 0 && -2 \[Pi] <= u <= 2 \[Pi], u], 0}
```

Comment: z isn't a function as I think

Comment: @openspace `z[u_]=Log[Tan[u/2]] + Cos[u]`